# How does "final" play a role in security?

Tags: java, security, final

I have read in [Wikipedia here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29) that:

> A final class cannot be subclassed. This is done for reasons of
>   security and efficiency.

I am wondering about the kind of security that `final` in Java can achieve?

Comment: @user93353 - Here's [a link from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html) that says the following about security and the _final_ keyword: "_It is better to design APIs with security in mind. Trying to retrofit security into an existing API is more difficult and error prone. For example, making a class final prevents a malicious subclass from adding finalizers, cloning, and overriding random methods (Guideline 4-5)._"  (It took about 2 seconds to find)

Comment: @user93353 - Here's another quote from the same [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html): "_Design classes and methods for inheritance or declare them final [6]. Left non-final, a class or method can be maliciously overridden by an attacker. A class that does not permit subclassing is easier to implement and verify that it is secure. Prefer composition to inheritance._"  If you read that document there are dozens of code examples that make use of the _final_ keyword... and they're not using it because it's fun.

Comment: Your duplicate question have attracted a large number of bad answer and comments. People are simply believing in everything they've read somewhere in internet. The original question has a reasonable answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2111887/531954

Comment: @ŁukaszLech - Nobody is claiming that using the keyword _final_ makes a piece of software completely secure.  The question is about how it can be used for "_reasons of security_", which Oracle seems to address repeatedly and thoroughly.

Comment: @jahroy but It's not Oraclanidy Q&A (as analogy to Christianity Q&A) - referenced to Oracle, Bible or Aristotle are not absolute arguments here, but something that needs to be proven. None of the answers have proven there's some reason behind the Oracle arguments, for example, would any attacker really try to 'maliciously override' a class instead of directly attacking the system? I've expressed my **opinion** by voting, but I'm not security expert. Let's move the question to Security Q&A and see what would be written there.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech - Again, I completely agree with every statement you've made that claims that the techniques recommended by Oracle do not provide complete security (there's no reason to prove anything).  All I'm saying is that **nobody is making the claim that you want to refute**.  Somebody is asking "_can a bike helmet make you more safe when you ride a bike_" and you're responding by saying "_no matter what helmet you wear, you could still get hit by a truck_".  We're going in circles... I concede you point entirely, but for some reason you can't even consider what anybody else is saying.

Comment: @jahroy no, for me it's like wearing a hat, it will protect you from cold, but it will give you absolutely no protection from damages. I may be wrong with it, but no one here has proved final gives *any* real protection, so I think the question should be asked on Security to let them play mythbusters.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech - Yes, that's exactly my point.  Wearing a hat provides some security (from a cold) but not complete security (from a truck).  Just like a final class in a banking API provides some security (it prevents it from being overridden by a malicious attacker), but not complete security (it doesn't prevent somebody from hacking the bank's computers or from breaking open the ATM with a sledgehammer and stealing the money).  I'd be happy to migrate this question, but I'm sure everyone will find this conversation to be absurd and pointless.

Comment: @jahroy and this is my point: how could a malicious attacker override a class, no matter final or not final, in first line? He would have to break into system first.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech - "_How could a malicious attacker override a class, no matter final or not final?_" If the class is in an API or a library and it is not final, a malicious attacker could override the class by using the _extends_ keyword.  I do this all the time with other peoples' libraries (in a non-malicious way).

Comment: @jahroy I don't understand - you want to protect your computer from yourself? Or the computer of malicious attacker from himself? It's certainly too much misunderstanding here, I'll move question to security.SE on the evening if no one makes that before.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech - Is it impossible to understand that library code could be executed on one computer that accesses another computer?  Or that the code might seek to restrict access to a password or some other local data?  If I develop a game that uses a library that accesses my game server, I would consider trying to make it difficult for others to use code from that library to perform malicious acts on my server. Yes, they can still hack into my server by writing their own code or breaking into my office (or by reverse engineering my library), but that's not what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech - This is a good question that was upvoted by 11 people.  We've basically ruined it with a completely unrelated series of debates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`final` does not provide any security whatsoever. It's silly to expect it to. It provides a kind of safety.

Though your question is related to java, I'll point you to Marshall Cline's C++ FAQ which answers a similar question.

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/encap-is-not-security.html

> [7.8] Is Encapsulation a Security device?
>
> No.
>
> Encapsulation != security.
>
> Encapsulation prevents mistakes, not espionage.

Let me add that the keywords like `public`, `private`, `final` etc do not prevent intentional misuse. They are just constructs which help enforce design by preventing accidental or unintentional misuse.

A programmer who wants to substitute functionality in the base class can use other ways to do it - the simplest is it to not use the class at all and do his own stuff.

If you want to prevent access or any other thing, do it in the underlying OS, not in your class library.

As always, Wikipedia may be a good starting point for something but is rarely the authoritative source.

Comment: Your link makes the worst argument out of any of anything written in this question.  If I want to be as pedantic as you've been in all your comments, I could just ay that the underlying OS cannot provide any security either, because somebody could just hack the machine or write their own code that exploits the OS' vulnerabilities... But that would be (yet another) inane comment.

Comment: A vulnerable OS isn't a secure OS. So such an OS should not claim it provides security.

Comment: Here's [a link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html) that actually discusses the use of the **final** keyword in **Java** (rather than a link that talks about **encapsulation** in **C++**)... Note that it's written by Oracle and is titled "_Secure coding guidelines for the Java programming language_".

Comment: It's the only reasonable answer in that thread. I can't believe how easly can people believe some language feature used for enforcing better encapsulation can magically make their code less vulnerable to malicious attacks.

Comment: `final` is very important in the context of the JVM running in a trusted process with mobile code that may be untrusted. Applets and RMI (old default config) are obvious old examples. You can't realistically do anything like that in C++.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech - I'm glad somebody who knows what they're talking about has finally visited this question (Tom Hawtin).  My examples may be flawed, but this answer is **not** valid.

Answer (score 16):

If your class is final, No one can subclass it.
If no one can subclass your final class, that means your features of the final class can not be changed by other by reusing your class.

Assume you are technology provider, here you provide API for some banking system, using your API client will implement its banking system.

case: WITHOUT FINAL

This is in your API

```
class BaseClass{
 public void makeTransaction(){
   }
}
```

This is client code

```
class DerivedClass extends BaseClass{
 public void makeTransaction(){
     // naughty client can do something here like:- makeTransaction but transfer 1 dollar for each transaction to my account.
   }
}
```

case: WITH FINAL
This is in your API

```
final class BaseClass{
 public void makeTransaction(){
   }
}
```

This is client code

```
class DerivedClass extends BaseClass{  // not allowed
}
```

Client has to use make transaction as you have already defined. This is one aspect how final can secure your piece of code.

Comment: upvote for a good example

Comment: False sense of security - if someone can execute arbitrary code, no language trick will make you secure.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech - Just because no _language trick_ will make something completely secure, it doesn't mean that some language tricks can't make something **more** secure.  You and user93353 are splitting hairs and missing the point.  There's a reason Oracle discusses the _final_ keyword extensively in its secure coding guidelines.

Comment: @jahroy I'm not missing the point, I'm agaist stimulating false security sense through techniques, that are not designed for it. It's just like 'securing' the system by proper capitalization of critical methods - it may make developers more aware what those methods are using, or it may not.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech - Yes, you are missing the point.  You claim that a keyword doesn't make a piece of software 100% secure.  That has nothing to do with the question and is indisputable.  You're getting caught up in semantics.  If the question was "_does the final keyword make my software completely secure_" everybody would agree with you immediately.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech What do you mean by sentence "if someone can execute arbitrary code", please elaborate.

Comment: Your words - "If no one can subclass your final class, that means your features of the final class can not be changed by other by reusing your class." - so if someone can subclass your class and put that code in your system, it means also he can run arbitrary code. In what other situation could that apply?

Comment: @ŁukaszLech I think things are going little out of context here. Security provided by final is in sense of accessibility. by re-using i mean "extending". If there is better word i would welcome your suggestion and edit the answer.

Comment: @GauravGupta: if we make public void makeTransaction() method final then also we can achieve security. What is the need to make class final.

Answer (score 4):

> A final class cannot be subclassed. This is done for reasons of
>   security and efficiency.I am wondering about the kind of security that
>   final in Java can achieve?

If a class cannot be subclassed then you cannot override the functionality that a parent class provides in a child class. From a design perspective you are actually finalizing and enforcing a design using final classes. Hence it makes your final class secured in that sense.

Answer (score 0):

If a class if final than none other class Inherit that class and the

> overriding of methods is not possible

.
For example, the String class is final so that no one can override and change the methods of the String class.

Comment: So how does that add security?

Comment: If I can override methods of String class than I can change the body of my overridden method and than if someone uses my class methods, like...
String s = new MyStringClass("hello");
s.reverse();
than he may get the different output...

Comment: How is preventing a different output adding security?

Comment: @user93353: Suppose a method is supposed to only allow access to files whose names start with "G:\".  If the method checks whether a string starts with those characters and passes that string [rather than a copy] to another method which opens a file with a specified name, code which changed the string between the time its leading characters were checked and the time it was passed to the other method could access arbitrary files on other drives.

Comment: @user93353: In cases requiring real security, code which receives a string should generate a new string containing the same characters and validate the copy, so that even if the supplier of the string is somehow able to modify the original, the string being validated would be the same one passed as a file name, but defensive copying isn't free, and not all methods use such techniques.

Comment: @user93353, if you want to stop access to files whose names don't start with "G:\", then you should use OS permissions to do that, and not use silly checks in your base class for that. If the OS allows me to access files whose names don't start with "G:\", then I will bypass your security by not calling your method at all & instead directly call file APIs to access the files I want to.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you work at the bank and your boss ask for a way to validate some customer credentials.

You will have something like that:

```
public class Validation {

    private Customer customer;

    public Validation(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public boolean validate() {
        return customer.isValid();
    }
}
```

You must put a final on the class or on the method validate(not sure why nobody mentioned it). This way, if someone wants to extend your class he won't change the validate algorithm(final on method) of he won't extend the class at all(final on class).

Comment: What if his code doesn't call the validate method at all or ignores the return value? What is final going to do to prevent that?

Comment: Well.... if the class is `final` than "_his code_" can't extend the class **OR** invoke any of the methods.

Comment: Nothing. But not final classes/methods won't be more sure either. You can of course encapsulate this validate function in another function. Let's say `public final double withdrawMoney(Customer customer, double money) { if (new Validation(customer).validate()) { return customer.withdrawMoney(money); } return 0; }` . I know, the code is not syntax sugar, but it was just a demo :)

Comment: The malicious developer may not use the `withdrawMoney` call at all. He may just use SQL directly to bypass your withdrawMoney security. Very little can be done against a malicious developer other than a lot of code review.

Comment: @jahroy what do you mean by `invoke any of the methods` ? You can invoke anything you want, as long as you have access(public, protected ..)

Comment: @user93353 what if my class is the only way to withdraw money and you cannot directly access customer's withdrawMoney without it? It's still you, the good developer, the creator of the flow. As long as you add the validate method on the road and other's cannot override the flow/validation, you're secure.

Comment: How would you invoke the private methods of _BaseClass_ if it's final?  I don't see what's so complicated about this.

Comment: I am out of this discussion - none of you guys seem to be able to differentiate between security and safety.

Comment: It doesn't have to be private and you can have a DAO bean to make the withdrawal, with a public method to be invoked(and final), with a call to validate() and a private method to do the business logic(check if he can withdraw the amount, do it or not, etc.). As I said previously, you make the rules.

Comment: @user93353 - You don't seem to be able to accept the fact that the word security doesn't always mean **exactly** what you want it to mean when you make your arguments.  If I told you I want to make my home more secure by adding an alarm system, you'd refute my logic by claiming you could still break into my house by blowing the roof off with a warhead.  I don't understand what you're trying to prove.